# NserviceBus RabbitMQ configuration on WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I have a webAPI project in which one of the controllers sends a command to a service(Nservicebus Host) which does additional processing.

I am having trouble running the project saying with TargetInvocationException for the below type
{Name = "RabbitMqTransport" FullName = "NServiceBus.Features.RabbitMqTransport"}

I made sure I have a reference to RabbitMQ in bin folder as per github issue.Not sure whats the problem.

I have a structure map registry class which instantiates IBus type with the below configuration..

```
 ForSingletonOf<IBus>().Use(
        NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .UseTransport<NServiceBus.RabbitMQ>()
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start(() =>          NServiceBus.Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing RabbitMQ.Client in the bin/debug folder where API is hosted. Ahh well....